# Stagger Sphinx Indexing

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I'm trying to create an index containing 37 million records.

I'm using a script to export the data from MySQL, and output this as XML, which is then being imported with xmlpipe2.

The problem I have, is the XML file being generated is considerably large, and the server I'm developing on doesn't have the memory to store the XML.

If I limit the amount of rows being imported, e.g. LIMIT 0, 1000000, when I then do LIMIT 1000000, 1000000, the index doesn't 'merge' as such, but overwrites.

Can I somehow stagger this so I eventually end up with an index of all the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than output to an actual XML file, just pipe the output direct to sphinx. That way they actual file never has to exist (in memory nor on the filesystem).

ie the script that you call in 'xmlpipe_command' just prints the XML direct to STDOUT. sphinx digests and reads it as it goes along.

I've read XML datasources many times bigger than the servers memory like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one source per index, like several xml files or several mysql sources. The index take them in the order you give them, just make sure the document id is unique across the sources.